# java Arrays.binarySearch gives wrong answer, but bitwise complement gives the right answer

Tags: java, arrays

GeeksForGeeks.com has a list of interesting and cool tricks in Java, one of which is mystifying to me. It gives the correct answer, I just have no idea why.

```
  import java.util.Arrays; 

        public class GFG { 
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            { 
                int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; 

                // 2 has to be inserted 
                int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 2); 
                System.out.print("Element has to be inserted at: "
                                                          + ~pos); 
            } 
        }
```

So it will correctly say that the location is 1 because pos = -2, and then after taking the bitwise complement, ~pos = 1, which is the correct location. But I'm wondering, why didn't it return 1 in the first place? And more mysteriously, why is it correct after taking the bitwise complement? Here's the orginal link to the GFG article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-and-cool-tricks-in-java/

Any advice from the Java guru's is appreciated!
Hank

Comment: Did you read the documentation about what it [returns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-)?

Comment: "why didn't it return 1 in the first place?" That would mean "2 is found at index 1", wouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed, I just read the fine manual - problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int)):

> Returns:
>       index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key.

Which means that, since Java uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent the negative of a number, if you negate the bits of the returned number you obtain the correct insertion point.

Comment: Sorry, I got a little sloppy there, didn't I! Well, this makes perfect sense now. It can't return a positive number if it's absent, so Java uses that opportunity to encode the location for insertion with a specific negative number. Ahhh, Java, such a beautiful language! I can't stay mad at her for long, can I? Seriously, thanks for the tip.